# django sort queryset by newest dates from different fields

Tags: python, django

How can I sort queryset just like forums do?

I mean ordering by one date field, and there will be another order date
to use for sorting, for example in forums: subjects get sorted by on created date (or updated date), but if any old subject got a new reply, then it will be shown *before* other subjects. This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

What I tried so far:

```
    subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-sticky', '-updated_date', 'reply__updated_date')
```

but in this case results are repeated as reply counts.

I've also tried:

```
    subjects = Subjects.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-sticky', '-updated_date').order_by('reply__updated_date')
```

but in this case the second `order_by` overrides the first one.

Is there any guideline to follow?

BTW, I'm pretty sure you got it, but just to be clear, `Subject` is a model and `Reply` is another model, connected by a foreign key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you can achieve this by using [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/).

One thing at a time.

1. You want to sort `Subjects` by **reply date** in **descending** order: in Django's own terms, you need to `annotate()` each `Subjects` with the maximun `updated_date` of its related model `reply`, and sort `Subjects` by the new field in reverse order, like this:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Max

   subjects = Subject.objects.annotate(lr=Max('reply__updated_date'))\
                     .order_by('-lr')
   ```
2. Now you have all subjects **with at least one reply** sorted, but what about the subjects **without replies**?

   We can rephrase our sorting like this: "sort by last reply date if there are replies, *and by last subject update otherwise*".

   The "otherwise" part can be achieved by the [Coalesce()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function, which replaces NULLs with another expression of our choice. In our case it'll replace what's inside Max() with the `updated_date` field **of the Subjects**:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Max
   from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

   subjects = Subject.objects\
                     .annotate(lr=Coalesce(Max('reply__updated_date'), 'updated_date'))\
                     .order_by('-lr')
   ```